# Crunchbang installation on netbook

Tags: software-installation, drivers, usb, crunchbang

I've recently installed crunchbang on my Compaq mini netbook, as the computer was not very powerful I chose crunchbang and was hoping to be able to use the computer mainly as a VPN server I could log in to from afar.

The netbook does not have a Ethernet cable, but I was able, through a lot of searching online, to determine and download the correct driver onto a USB device, from which I am now trying to install the driver.

I got the driver and some help from [the Broadcom site](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)

How can I install the driver for the wireless network from the USB device?

Comment: Maybe look [here](http://codelinks.pachanka.org/post/57506957174/wifi-not-working-in-crunchbang-with-acer-aspire-as5733). Downloading the `broadcom-sta-dkms` or the binaries for it in a [package form](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=broadcom) would at least allow you to use the `dpkg` command to install and insures this remains managed and you don't extract files and then have a hard time undoing changes later on... this driver is packaged by the distributions. Usually it is not required to manipulate files like you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Download all packages from http://packages.debian.org/sid/build-essential marked as depends (red circle) and all dependencies of those packages (recusively). Put them in one directory and run

```
# dpkg -i *.deb
```

Next, build your driver. `cd` to directory with downloaded package and run

```
tar -xvf your-file.tar.gz
./configure && make && make install
```